# Variance of a single measurement

Tags: variance, least-squares

Say that I have a collection of $n$ data points: $x_i, y_i, i = 0, \ldots, n-1$, and $x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_{n-1}$. The $x_i$ are the independent data, and the $y_i$ are the dependent data (measurements).

I have seen several references (given below), in the context of both linear regression and in smoothing splines, to the notion of $\sigma_i^2$ being the "variance associated with each measurement $y_i$."

For example, in NR p 781, eq (15.2.2), discussing linear regression, the chi-square merit function is given as:
$$\chi^2(a, b) = \sum_{i=0}^{n - 1}\left(\frac{y_i - a - bx_i}{\sigma_i} \right)^2$$
The description in the text is "We assume that the uncertainty $\sigma_i$ associated with each measurement $y_i$ is known..."

Likewise, in SS p 177, eq (2), discussing smoothing splines, a minimization condition is given as:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\left(\frac{g(x_i) - y_i}{\delta y_i} \right)^2 \leq S$$
The description in the text is "If available, one should use for $\delta y_i$ an estimate of the standard deviation of the ordinate $y_i$."

But, I only have my $n$ data points, and would have to estimate $\sigma_i$ (or $\delta y_i$) from those data points, rather than have them known or supplied prior.

My question is, how can this be done?

I am currently estimating the value with $\sigma_i = |y_i - \bar{y}|$, where $\bar{y}$ is the "nearest neighbor" mean of $y_{i-1}$, $y_i$, and $y_{i+1}$, but this doesn't feel quite right. How can I more correctly/accurately estimate $\sigma_i$ for each $y_i$?

**References**

[NR]: Press, William et al. (2007) *Numerical Recipes*, 3e. Cambridge University Press.

[SS]: Reinsch, Christian. (1967) "Smoothing by Spline Functions", *Numerische Mathematick*, 10, pp 177-183.